# How to bind DataGridView to SubList

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a Singleton BindingList list with objects.

I need to bind this list to DataGridView. 
I need the grid to show only objects with specific property value (Property IsEmpty and I want to show only objects with IsEmpty=false).

I tried to iterate trough the DataGridView rows after the bind completed and hide rows with IsEmpty=false. This worked but the grid doesn't work well in some situation like sorting of columns.

My conclusion is I need to have a sublist of the original list with refrence to all the objects in the original list that have property IsEmpty=true.

Any idea what is the best way for doing this? (I need to preserve the ListChanged event in the new list for the binding work well)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to filter your data source **before** binding to your grid.  The best way would like be with a call to linq's `Where` method.

```
IEnumerable<yourType> initialSource = getYourSource();
yourGrid.DataSource = initialSource.Where(x => !x.IsEmpty).ToList();
```

This will keep your original collection intact, and will bind the grid only to those objects that match the filter.

**Edit**

If you can't use linq, then why not a simple loop?

```
List<yourType> filteredSource = new List<yourType>();
foreach(var item in initialSource)
    if (!item.isEmpty)
       filteredSource.Add(item);

yourGrid.DataSource = filteredSource;
```

Comment: I'm using .net framework 2.0 so no Linq for me.

I can create a method that creates sublist of the original list only with object where IsEmpty=false and pass that as the data source. I think it's the same as you suggest.

The problem is that if the original list will be updated with new object for example the sublist won't have this object